# Import * from python

Tags: python-import

I have a script named MyScript.py . I want to import all my script without running one/two rows, is it possible ?

for example:
in my new script :

- import MyScript (will run all my rows)
- from MyScript import * ( I want to run all excepting one row)

i want to make this condition in the second script without change anything on the first MyScript.py

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

No, what you are asking for is not possible using only import.
There is an option if you are willing to modify MyScript.py. Also consider packaging the code in `MyScript` in functions, so you can control exactly what code will be executed from your second script.

If you have code in your `MyScript` script that should not be executed when importing the script, surround that part with `if \_\_name__ == '\_\_main__'`:

So for example:

```py
# File MyScript
import numpy as np  # will be executed on import

class MyClass:
   def __init__(self, something):
       self.something = something
   
   def some_method():
       return None

if __name__ == '__main__'
    # everything in here will not be executed on import
    print("Hello World")
```

When you import, all the code in the file will be executed, e.g. creating the class and importing numpy. The if statement `if \_\_name__ = '\_\_main__'` will also be executed, however, the condition will evaluate to false (as the special `\_\_name__` variable is not set to `\_\_main__` when you import) and therefore the code inside the if statement will not be executed. If you run the script directly from command line, the code will be executed since then `\_\_name__` is set to `\_\_main__`.

Answer (score 0):

### I fond a method to do it.

#### MyScript.py

```
import pandas as pd
import os

print('yes')

if 'PROD' in os.environ:
    print('all script')
```

### When I want to run all the script I do :

#### Prod.py

```
import os
os.environ['PROD'] = 'PROD'
import MyScript
```

### if I just want to test without run all script:

#### Test.py

```
import MyScript
```